# I need a way to detect last Five clicks time on my UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, nstimer

I have an `UIButton` that the user must click on it 5 times in three seconds, im trying to implement a method for that, but im getting the correct result if the user clicked on the button 5 times in 3 seconds in a row, if the user clicked once and stopped for 2 seconds for example, the counter take the first click in the calculation.

in a short words, i need a method that detect the last five clicks and know if the clicks were in three second or not...

Here is my old code:

```
-(void)btnClicked{
 counter++;

if (totalTime <=3 && counter==5) {

        NSLog(@"My action");
        // My action
}}
```

I know that my code is too simple, so that why i asked you pro's

Comment: Maybe an NSTimer would be appropriate.  Hold on, let me write you some pseudo-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try altering this example appropriately:

```
// somewhere in the initialization - counter is an int, timedOut is a BOOL
counter = 0;
timedOut = NO;

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)btn
{
    if ((++counter >= 5) && !timedOut) {
        NSLog(@"User clicked button 5 times within 3 secs");

        // for nitpickers
        timedOut = NO;
        counter = 0;
    }
}

// ...

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(timedOut)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO
];

- (void)timedOut
{
    timedOut = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply have an array with the timestamp of the last four clicks, and every time there is a click, check if the previous four are within 3 seconds from the current time.  If it is not the case, discard the oldest timestamp and replace with current time, but if it is the case, you got your event and you can clear the array so that they are not used in the next 5-clicks-in-3-seconds event.

Comment: Isn't implementing a FIFO queue a bit overengineering this?

Comment: well, he can just implement an array, and forget about the pushing/pulling abstraction.

Comment: changed to array in case the fifo concept seems like too much.

Comment: I think this is much easier both to understand and implement right than fiddling with timers. There's no magic background thing going on, very clear at all times what you are evaluating against, and what behavior to expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 'my version' of H2CO3's code. This should suit your requirement better.

```
int counter = 0;
BOOL didTimeOut = NO;

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
    counter ++;
    if (counter == 1) {
        didTimeOut = NO;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0f
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(timedOut)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO
         ];
    } else {
        if ((counter >= 5) && !didTimeOut) {
            //Do your action as user clicked 5 times in 3 seconds

            counter = 0;
            didTimeOut = NO;
        }
    }

}

- (void)timedOut {
    didTimeOut = YES;
}
```

Comment: That will not detect the last 5 clicks , its detect 5 clicks in a row at one time